# FileNotFoundException when reading from text document

Tags: exception, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a file from

```
public static void printLines(String doc){

    Scanner input = null;
    input = new Scanner(doc + ".txt")); 

    while(input.hasNext()){

        String nextLine = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(nextLine);

    }

    input.close;

}
```

The code above is from a method that takes in String doc as a parameter, and prints out every line. In my main, I used a try catch block to catch a FileNotFoundException. However, when I try running the program, it hits FileNotFoundException all the time.

I'm using Eclipse and the text file and java file are both in the same "Java Project". Is there any reason why my method can't read the text file? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to print the `doc` inside it. It may be including the extension of the file too.

For example, if the doc is `/home/user/Desktop/mySample.txt` the Scanner will try to find `/home/user/Desktop/mySample.txt.txt` which is not available, because you are concatenating the extension `.txt` again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting FileNotFoundException is that you're using the wrong constuctor of Scanner.

Change `input = new Scanner(doc + ".txt"));` to

`input = new Scanner(new File(doc + ".txt")));` should suit your need.